# Naming AsyncTask for profiling in Android

Tags: android, profiling, android-asynctask

Is there any way to name AsyncTasks in Android for the purposes of profiling? As of now, the AsyncTasks only shows up in the profiler as

```
[N] AsyncTask #1
[M] AsyncTask #2
[K] AsyncTask #3
[L] AsyncTask #4
etc...
```

What I would like to do is to be able to name them in some way to easily identify them in the trace file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can rename current thread from code that run in the thread. For example, add next code in your `doInBackground()` function:

```
String oldName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
Thread.currentThread().setName("MY-ASYNC");
...   
<your code here>
...
Thread.currentThread().setName(oldName);
```

Comment: Another trick I like is to extend AsyncTask to create my own abstract base for background tasks, and in doInBackground() you can do something like Thread.currentThread().setName(this.class.getSimpleName());  This will translate properly for child classes.

Comment: Why would you want to call at the end setName(oldName) ?

Comment: @aleb, because async tasks use pool and we want to keep original name of thread once task is complete. This way you won't be confused by seeing thread "ASYNC-TASK-X" that is running something completely different because thread was reused by the pool while name was "leaked".

Comment: +1 for setting the old name back